# Aloha Editor does not work on Opera, and sometimes does not work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, aloha-editor

I've been using Aloha Editor to create an [example of a simple editor](https://github.com/pereorga/infinite-docs), but I haven't succeed to getting it to work in Opera. The menu doesn't appear and the textarea is not editable.

In all other browsers seems to work fine, but sometimes Chrome needs to refresh the page to work.

This is the relevant HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="//cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="content"></textarea>
    <script src="//cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/require.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/ui,common/format,common/table,common/list,common/link,common/block,common/undo,common/contenthandler,common/paste"></script>
    <script src="notes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the javascript code (inside **notes.js**):

```
var Aloha = window.Aloha || ( window.Aloha = {} );
Aloha.settings = { sidebar: { disabled: true } };

Aloha.ready(function () {

    Aloha.jQuery('#content').aloha();

});
```

Comment: I tried it in chrome, but was unable to reproduce the problem - it worked every time. Didn't try it in opera. One potential problem is that you are initializing the settings after including Aloha. Instead try to put the `Aloha.settings = {...};` before you include the aloha.js script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question after reading the comment from Inshallah.

The problem was that the JavaScript variables *Aloha* and *Aloha.settings* should be set before including Aloha.

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="//cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="content"></textarea>
    <script src="//cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Aloha = window.Aloha || ( window.Aloha = {} );
        Aloha.settings = { sidebar: { disabled: true } };
    </script>
    <script src="//cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/ui,common/format,common/table,common/list,common/link,common/block,common/undo,common/contenthandler,common/paste"></script>
    <script src="notes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript code (inside *notes.js*)**

```
Aloha.ready(function () {
    Aloha.jQuery('#content').aloha();
});
```